# parsing coordinates from a SVG translate string in PHP

Tags: php, string, svg

I am in a search of a best way to parse SVG's transform coordinates into X and Y variables. Transform coordinates are stored in string attribute with format  `"translate(32.84441676851017  11.803819679481) rotate(0)"`. I need to parse values `$x=32.84441676851017` and `$y=11.803819679481`.

So far I am using this self written function, but I guess there s gotta be faster way of parsing this?

```
private function _get_string_between($s, $str1, $str2) 
{
    $start = strpos($s, $str1);
    if ($start === false) {
    return '';
    }

    $start += strlen($str1);
    $end = strpos($s, $str2, $start); 
    if ($end === false) {
    return '';
    }

    return explode(' ', substr($s, $start, $end - $start));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a scan function that can read float values from within a string:

```
sscanf($string, 'translate(%f %f) rotate(0)', $x, $y);
```

See [`sscanf`](http://php.net/sscanf), [Demo](http://codepad.org/Hgb4CZRn)

Answer (score 2):

Use [d3.transform(string)](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Math#wiki-d3_transform)

Example:

```
 var theta = d3.transform($("#svg-element").attr("transform")).rotate;
```